# Wordpressで生成されるRSSフィードについて

Tags: wordpress

お世話になります。
表題の通り、Wordpressで生成されるRSSフィードについて教えてください。
例えば、
example.com/feed
のように指定すると、RSSフィードを取得できると思います。
ですが、このURLにFirefoxでアクセスすると、「feed」というファイルがダウンロードされてしまいます。
ちなみに、GoogleChromeでは、ブラウザ上で直接表示されました。まあ、ソースがそのまま表示されるだけですが。
これをFirefoxでもブラウザ上に表示させるようにする方法はありますでしょうか。
確か以前のバージョンではブラウザ上で表示されていたと思うんですが。
何か.htaccessで設定等が必要なのでしょうか。
アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefoxでのフィードリーダー機能は バージョン64 で廃止されました。

https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/live-bookmarks

> **2018 年 12 月**: Firefox の組み込みフィードリーダーとライブブックマークは、Firefox バージョン 64 以降、削除されました。代替については、Firefox 向けのフィードリーダーの置き換え をご覧ください。

代替案としてアドオンで対応する方法があるようです。

[「Firefox 64」で廃止されたフィードプレビューとライブブックマークを復活させたい！ - 窓の杜](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/serial/yajiuma/1158354.html)

Comment: お世話になります。なるほど、Firefoxの変更が原因だったのですね。ありがとうございました。